# Dynamic programming problem constructing of base station

Tags: algorithm

Recently I'm learning a new strategy known as dynamic programming (DP) and greedy algorithm in algorithm course. However I'm having some trouble. Here is a coding assignment and for which I have no idea whether DP is the correct strategy, here is the problem:

> There are *N* villages lined up in a row. In these villages, some of them need to be selected to build base stations, where the coverage radius of each base station is *R*. Suppose a base station is placed at village *i*, and the coordinate of village *i* is *X_i*
> ​
> , then in [*X_i - R*, *X_i+R*], villages can be covered by this base station.
> Given the coordinates of all villages, find the minimum number of base stations required for all villages to be covered by base stations.

Suppose the input *N_i*'s are monotonically increasing. I'm trying to solve this problem by DP strategy, by constructing a 2d array `dp[i][j]`, where i = 1, 2, ..., N and j = 1, 2, ..., R, in order to record the minimum number of base stations required when there are *i* villages and the covering radius is *j*. But I'm not sure how to find the recursive formula this way.

Is there something wrong with my array construction? Or DP is not the best choise there? Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyse your DP approach first:

1. Why do you need a second parameter `j` for covering radius, since that is a fixed value `R` for all stations?
2. Let's say `dp[i+1] = count of stations to cover villages (i+1)..n`. While calculating `dp[i]`, you'll need to keep a track of the outermost range till now (that is, for any existing station in i+1...n, will `i` be covered in it's range or not)

To remove these unncessary complications, we can actually remove the dynamic programming approach by looking at a greedy property. The range of each station is `2*R (R in each direction)`. So, starting with the first village, find the rightmost village at a maximum distance `R` and add a station there. See how many villages get covered in the `R` range to the right of this station now. For the first house outside this range, increment the station count, and repeat the approach.

In my opinion, DP seems like a convoluted approach to solve a simple problem which can be done in `O(n)` time and constant space for a sorted input.

Edit:
To clear the confusion: if there are overlapping sub-problems in the greedy solution, then it makes sense to use DP. There is no point in storing results of sub-problems if they never overlap, since that means they'll only be computed once.
Greedy and DP don't conflict/contradict, they can be used simultaneously.

Comment: I'm just wondering that, in general, the greedy algorithm cannot always gives you the optimal strategy cuz the accumulation of locally best choice may not be the global best choice, but DP can. So is it reasonable to think that for any problem that the greedy stratagy works, they can also be solved by DP?

Comment: _"greedy algorithm cannot always gives you the optimal strategy"_: that's correct, if you can not prove the optimality of the greedy solution. DP just involves storing the results of subproblems to avoid recomputation.

Comment: So if the correctness of greedy can be proved (for instance in this case),  we use greedy, otherwise we can only use DP, is that right?

Comment: @Scanners no. If there are overlapping sub-problems in the greedy solution, then it makes sense to use DP. There is no point in storing results of sub-problems if they never overlap, since that means they'll only be computed once

Comment: I still have some confusions, but thanks a lot anyway~

Comment: @Scanners what isn't clear exactly?

Comment: emmmmm I think I've got it. DP is just a stratagy to avoid re-computing caused by overlapping, it does not contradict with greedy, they can be used simultaneously.

Comment: @kcsquared that's what I had intended, wasn't explicitly clear though. Good point, edited the answer to include that